# Compare value of two nodes of same type using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. I need help comparing the value of two nodes in same element of XML.

My sample XML:

```
<Bank>
<BankName Name="ICICI" Id="101">
    <Customer>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Accno>121</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c123</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Accno>122</Accno>
        <City>Gurgaon</City>
        <Balance>30000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c125</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Accno>123</Accno>
        <City>Dehradun</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c124</Pancard>
    </Customer>
</BankName>
<BankName Name="PNB" Id="102">
    <Customer>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Accno>221</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>30000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c123</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Accno>222</Accno>
        <City>Gzb</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>p123</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Accno>223</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>p122</Pancard>
    </Customer>
</BankName>
<BankName Name="SBI" Id="103">
    <Customer>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Accno>321</Accno>
        <City>Dehradun</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c124</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Accno>322</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>40000</Balance>
        <Pancard>s123</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Accno>323</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>30000</Balance>
        <Pancard>p122</Pancard>
    </Customer>
</BankName>
</Bank>
```

I would like to fetch nodes (in XML) with BankName and Customer details where **Pancard no. is same** for customers in same or different banks.

Output Like :

```
<Bank>
<BankName Name="ICICI">
    <Customer>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Accno>121</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c123</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Accno>123</Accno>
        <City>Dehradun</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c124</Pancard>
    </Customer>
</BankName>
<BankName Name="PNB">
    <Customer>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Accno>221</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>30000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c123</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Accno>223</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>p122</Pancard>
    </Customer>
</BankName>
<BankName Name="SBI">
    <Customer>
        <Name>E</Name>
        <Accno>321</Accno>
        <City>Dehradun</City>
        <Balance>20000</Balance>
        <Pancard>c124</Pancard>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Accno>323</Accno>
        <City>Delhi</City>
        <Balance>30000</Balance>
        <Pancard>p122</Pancard>
    </Customer>
</BankName>
</Bank>
```

Comment: "*fetch nodes (in XML) with BankName and Customer details where Pancard no. is same for customers in diffrent banks.*"  **1.** Do you mean you want to detect **duplicate** `Pancard` values? What if they are in the same bank? ---  **2.** Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 and post the expected output of the transformation.

Comment: Yeah Exactly, I want to detect customers of diffrent or same bank having same pancard no. ,Using xslt 2.0 . I am updating the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="cust-by-pan" match="Customer" use="Pancard" />
<xsl:variable name="duplicates" select="Bank/BankName/Customer[count(key('cust-by-pan', Pancard)) gt 1]" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BankName[not(Customer intersect $duplicates)]"/>
<xsl:template match="Customer[not(. intersect $duplicates)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Worked Perfect for me !!... Thanks a lot